# How can I get a Countdown Timer to work in Angular 10

Tags: angular, timer, nativescript-angular, angular10, angular-compiler

I am attempting to create an Angular-Nativescript shared app that executes some function when a timer reaches zero.
I would also like the timer to restart/reset when the end value is changed.

In Angular 9, this functionality was working with the [angular-countdown-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-countdown-timer) package.

However, since upgrading to Angular 10, I can't get past the `ModuleWithProviders` requiring some generic type issue.

I have also tried using [angular8-countdown-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular8-countdown-timer) which works when the end value is set on page load but not afterwards (even though the end value in the component is changing).

I also tried some of the older packages like [ngx-countdown-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-countdown-timer-date) but no joy as they general fall foul of the `ModuleWithProviders` restriction.

I've tried using `ModuleWithProviders<any>` and `ModuleWithProviders<unknown>` as I've seen suggested in similar posts but the compiler just laughs in my face.

Any help with any of the above or even a way to contact the authors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question completely, but I just [updated my own angular9 project](https://github.com/JoSSte/ScrumTimer/commit/928d64e339f1ea47cd040a5b576092880a54ecc5) to use a slightly more efficient timer, where I am not importing all of rxjs.

I use several counters on the page and serveral resets.

Essentially when I start a timer I generate a new one, and do work when the interval elapses, and then stop the subscription when the stop button is clicked. In order to do what you want, I would guess you just call the `.unsubscribe()` function from inside the "do stuff" block.

I hope this helps you, or others coming here looking to time stuff in angular 8-10

```js
import { Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';

...
  subscription: Subscription;


  startTimer(){
    const source = timer(1000, 2000);
    this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => {
       // do stuff you want when the interval ticks
    }
  }

  stopTimer(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

My inspiration is [this article](https://www.djamware.com/post/5da31946ae418d042e1aef1d/angular-8-tutorial-observable-and-rxjs-examples).

Comment: Thanks for this JoSSte. I am only now revisiting this. Will try your solution out

Comment: I should've added I wanted to display a countdown clock until the action is triggered so having something that covered all that heavy lifting was preferred (ie <countdown #cd [config]="{leftTime: countDownSeconds, demand: false}" (event)="changeTime()"></countdown>) but will try your approach do some more manual handling

Comment: maybe you can update your question and add that information